# Can you programmatically change your application's widths to fluid?

Tags: facebook, canvas, width

I have a lot of applications and I want to change the width from fixed to fluid. I usually use the fql to change my app properties, but don't know if there is a settable one for canvas width yet.

Can you programmatically change your applications widths to fluid? if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you can. I ran a query using the Graph API explorer tool and it doesn't return any information about canvas width and the FQL documents or any of the blog posts I found don't mention a way to do it via an FQL call either!